# HTTP Post API. Request args well formed but not recognised in db. Return 400 or 404?

Tags: rest, api, http

GIVEN a HTTP Post API endpoint as follows:

```
http://localhost/context-root/{value}
```

and a request body which is well formed for an entity:

```
{
 "key":value
}
```

WHEN the URL `value` corresponds to a value which needs to exist in a backend database prior to the POST call

AND the value is not present in the backend database

AND the request body is well formed

AND we should communicate failure to persist the request body to the database on this basis

SHOULD the HTTP response code be 400 or 404?

Comment: I am asking this question because I am specifically tripped up by the semantics when considering a POST call. Virtually all other questions I've seen on SO are for GET requests., but I feel this is a bit different because we're posting data on the assumption that there is some pre-requisite data which is already present. I want to understand how this data affects the semantics of the HTTP POST response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SHOULD the HTTP response code be 400 or 404?

I'd probably use [404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) myself.

Here's what the standard has to say about [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)

> ...almost all of the status codes defined by this specification might be received in a response to POST (the exceptions being 206 (Partial Content), 304 (Not Modified), and 416 (Range Not Satisfiable)).

So if we accept that `404` is an acceptable status code to use in the response to a POST request, what else could it mean?

Informally, `404` directs the clients attention to the request-target element of the [request line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1), which is probably what you want in this circumstance.

Part of the point of HTTP is that the protocol disguises the underlying implementation of the resource.  From this outside point of view, it is immaterial whether the implementation is a plugin running within the http server process that talks to a database, or a CGI script.

So an experiment you could try: choose some bog standard HTTP server, configure it such that it treats any request to /context-root/{value} as a CGI request, then review what response you receive when the necessary script is not available.

But I don't think the REST police are going to come after you if you guess the "wrong" thing.  Semantics aside, the practical difference between the two codes is that 404 is [cacheable by default](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.1), but 400 is not.  Caches are [not permitted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4) to return responses for requests with unsafe methods, and the rules for [invalidating a previously cached response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) are the same for both `400` and `404`.

Conclusion: use `404`, and if anybody really cares enough to submit a pull request, you can consider their arguments later.